# String lower method does not retain the generic type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

```
def cart(fruit: Literal["apple", "orange"]):
    print(fruit)


my_fruit = "Apple"

cart(my_fruit.lower()) # <======= SYNTAX ERROR
```

```
Argument of type "LiteralString" cannot be assigned to parameter "fruit" of type "Literal['apple', 'orange']" in function "cart"
  Type "LiteralString" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['apple', 'orange']"
    "LiteralString" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['apple']"
    "LiteralString" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['orange']"
```

I also tried but got the same error as above:

```
my_fruit = "Apple"

my_fruit_in_lowercase = my_fruit.lower()

cart(my_fruit_in_lowercase) # <======= SYNTAX ERROR
```

Type of `my_fruit_in_lowercase` is `LiteralString` when it should be `Literal['apple']`

Comment: The way you have type-hinted the function the only two valid invocations are `cart('orange')` & `cart('apple')`.

Comment: Yes, because the type checker can’t tell the result of a transformation through a generic function. You’d need to explicitly `cast` it to the known result value; but of course, if you know that, you don’t need the transformation to begin with.

Comment: I don't get any error?

Comment: That won't even work _without_ `.lower`: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=bed740a7d930dcd8212533c11009ff0e

Comment: Those aren't `SyntaxError`s, and they don't come from Python but from an external type-checking tool. Also, there  is no possible way that `str.lower` could "retain" the type, because `"Apple"` - not being a valid instance of `Literal["apple", "orange"]` - *doesn't have it in the first place*.

Answer (score 1):

The type of [`lower`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/6e985ef3de3678676d753a1efbf45fd67095a3b2/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L473) is

```
@overload
def lower(self: LiteralString) -> LiteralString: ...
@overload
def lower(self) -> str: ...  # type: ignore[misc]
```

It takes `LiteralString` to `LiteralString` and arbitrary strings to strings. Anything more would be a bizarre special case in the type system. Python's gradual typing rules do not do arbitrary code evaluation, and as well they shouldn't; that's not the domain of a type checker.